# Swift Firestore using an Array to get document fields

Tags: arrays, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am using an array named PosterEmail to search for a document field name "First Name" in my Firestore Database.

Here you can see my database set up.

[FirebaseSetup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFPwx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pytS3.png)

As you can see my Database is Public then in the document I have the user's email as the document name and in that document I have their information such as their first name, last name, and profile photo url.

I search for the document id using an Array

The PosterEmail array is

> > PosterEmail = ["chainsawloco@yahoo.com", "allmight@gmail.com", "allmight@gmail.com", "chainsawloco@yahoo.com"]

I am going through my PosterEmail index by setting a variable "profilecount" to 0 and adding 1 to it everytime to go through the PosterArray

```
let docRef = db.collection("Public").document("\(self.PosterEmail[self.profilecount])")
```

But it seems that the code above never searches for the Firebase document named after the second item in my Array

The result is just

> ["Irving ", "Irving ", "Irving ", "Irving "]

The result should end up as [Irving, Allmight, Allmight, Irving]

Is there something I"m doing wrong?

> Below is where I call my getPosteInformation() in another method called getDatFromFirestore()  (ehhh I know my method name has a typo but I can fix that later)

```
               if let postedBy = document.get("postedBy") as? String {
                    print("Postby = document.get(postedby = \(postedBy)")
                    self.PosterEmail.append(postedBy)

                    if self.PosterEmail.count > 0 {
                               self.getPosteInformation()
                          }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Below you can see my full code.

```
func getDatFromFirestore() {

    let firestoreDatabase = Firestore.firestore()

    firestoreDatabase.collection("Posts").order(by: "Date" , descending : true).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Connection Error")
        } else {
            self.userPostImageArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            self.userCommentArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            self.userCommentArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            self.likeArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            self.PosterEmail.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            self.userProfilePhotoArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            self.PosterFirstNameArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            self.PosterLastNameArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

            for document in snapshot!.documents {

                let documentID = document.documentID

                self.documentIDArray.append(documentID)

                if let postDescription = document.get("PostDescription") as? String {
                    self.userPostDescription.append(postDescription)
                }

                if let imageUrl = document.get("imageUrl") as? String {
                    self.userPostImageArray.append(imageUrl)
                }

                if let PostLikes = document.get("Likes") as? Int {
                    self.likeArray.append(PostLikes)
                }

                if let postTimeStamp = document.get("Date") as? Timestamp {

                    let date = postTimeStamp.dateValue()

                    let formatter = DateFormatter()
                    formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm MM/dd/yyyy"
                    let dateString = formatter.string(from: date)
                    let timeStampAsString = dateString

                    self.postDate.append(timeStampAsString)
                }

                if let postedBy = document.get("postedBy") as? String {
                    print("Postby = document.get(postedby = \(postedBy)")
                    self.PosterEmail.append(postedBy)

                    if self.PosterEmail.count > 0 {
                               self.getPosteInformation()
                           }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    self.VidaFeed.reloadData()
}

func getPosteInformation() {

    print("")
    print(PosterEmail[profilecount])
    print(profilecount)
    print("")


    print(PosterEmail)
    let docRef = db.collection("Public").document("\(self.PosterEmail[self.profilecount])")

    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
            print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")

            if self.profilecount < self.PosterEmail.count {

                if let PosterFirstName = document.get("First Name") as? String {
                    self.PosterFirstNameArray.append(PosterFirstName)
                    print(self.PosterFirstNameArray)

                    print("\(self.profilecount)")
                    if self.PosterEmail.count > self.profilecount {
                        self.profilecount = self.profilecount + 1
                    }

                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you call this method?

Comment: I call this method in another database reference. I have updated my question to include where I call the method.

Comment: Could you try incrementing the profile count inside your caller method right after calling the  getPosteInformation method.

Comment: I have incremented the profile count inside my caller method right after calling getPosteInformation(). The result is now ["AllMight", "AllMight", "Irving ", "Irving "], but it seems to be out of order. The result order should be [Irving, Allmight, Almight, Irving]. Is there a way to order the results?

Comment: What do you get in log for this line 'print(PosterEmail[profilecount])' ?

Comment: Also you could try looping through the posteremail array to call the method after you have gathered all the values in poster email.

Comment: the print(PosterEmail[profilecount] is correct which I get the emails in order. [chainsawloco@yahoo.com, allmight@gmail.com, allmight@gmail.com, chainsawloco@Yahoo.com], but my PosterFirstNameArray results in a different order of first names [allmight, allmight, irving, irving] when it should be [Irving, Allmight, Allmight, Irving]

Comment: @luckystars how can I loop through the posteremail array to call the method after I gathered all the values in my posteremail. Btw thanks for the help. I would Love to give you coffee money or something else if it works.

Comment: docRef.getDocument is an async method, so it cannot guarantee the results coming back in the order it was called

Comment: ha ha! thanks man. great offer, I might take you up on that one later. But we digress. This comment section is too short to post the solution I would have tried.

Comment: @luckystars is there a way to share the project with you?

Comment: I have posted the solution, theoretically this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
           if let postedBy = document.get("postedBy") as? String {
                print("Postby = document.get(postedby = \(postedBy)")
                self.PosterEmail.append(postedBy)
                self.PosterFirstNameArray.append("")

                if self.PosterEmail.count > 0 {
                   self.getPosteInformation(profCount: self.profileCount)
                }

                if self.PosterEmail.count > self.profilecount {
                    self.profilecount = self.profilecount + 1
                }
            }
```

And now if you could modify this method like this:

```
            func getPosteInformation(profCount:Int) {

                //and inside the async call back instead of the following try 
                /*if let PosterFirstName = document.get("First Name") as? String {
                self.PosterFirstNameArray.append(PosterFirstName)
                print(self.PosterFirstNameArray)

                print("\(self.profilecount)")
                if self.PosterEmail.count > self.profilecount {
                    self.profilecount = self.profilecount + 1
                }

                }*/

                if let PosterFirstName = document.get("First Name") as? String              {
                self.PosterFirstNameArray[profCount] = PosterFirstName
                print(self.PosterFirstNameArray)

                print("\(profCount)")


            }

            }
```

Comment: I'm getting a few errors. It says some of the of the variables do not exist

Comment: which variables? compile time error or run time error?

Comment: http://pastie.org/p/1ltqaE3v4kvVBml2Q4QnnO here is a copy of my full code. Btw thank you so much for the help

Comment: Right, ok, the first error is a spelling mistake, it should be self.profilecount instead of self.profileCount. And I am assuming you do not have these errors anymore as you have modified the methods correctly. I am curious to know if you got your first names in order now?

Comment: Yes the names are in order :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I been stuck on this for weeks! I would love to give you some coffee or beer money!

Comment: Glad I was of help. When I'll open up a patreon account, you'll be the first one I would approach for support. Promise. ;)

Comment: Thanks let me know! Thank you so much and take care